# How to find points in a CCRibbon or CCMotionStreak?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision, points

In my game, I need to check collision between an object and a line drawn using CCMotionStreak( or CCRibbon)... For that I need the points in the streak... But, I'm not able to get them... Can somebody please help to retrieve the current points being displayed in a CCMotionStreak or CCRibbon that's not faded yet?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Regards,

Suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if you can access it but there is an array available..

Since CCMotionStreak uses CCRibbon.. There is a mutablearray called segments_

It stores all the current visible ribbons..

Hope it helps..

Comment: I checked the mutablearray, segments_; But it contains only two objects at any time I check...